# Inserting rows into MySQL database from registration page

Tags: php, database

I am writing a script in PHP to insert users into a table in a database. here is the code:

```
<?php
$email      = check_input($_POST['EmailAddress'], "Enter your email address");
$pass       = check_input($_POST['Password'], "Enter a password");
$first_name = check_input($_POST['FirstName'], "Enter your first name");
$last_name  = check_input($_POST['LastName'], "Enter your last name");
$gender     = check_input($_POST['Gender']);
$dobmonth   = check_input($_POST['dobmonth']);
$dobday     = check_input($_POST['dobday']);
$dobyear    = check_input($_POST['dobyear']);
$dob        = $dobmonth.'/'.$dobday.'/'.$dobyear;
$phone      = check_input($_POST['CellPhone']);
$fanmail    = check_input($_POST['FanMail']);

if (verify($email) === true) {
```

edited from here:

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost","263764","Corvette88", "256764 ");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
} else {
    echo 'connected to db table ';
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$query = "INSERT INTO 68_users VALUES ('$email','$pass','$first_name','$last_name','$dob','$gender','$phone','$fanmail')" or die(mysql_error());
if ( !mysqli_query($link, $query) ) {
echo 'error: '.mysqli_error($link);
exit();
}

echo "1 record added ";

mysqli_close($link);
```

to here..

```
echo"connection closed";
} else {echo'unverifiable email address ';
    echo $email;
}


function check_input($data, $problem='') {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0) {
    die($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function conntodb() {

}

function verify($email){
$isValid = true;
$atIndex = strrpos($email,'@');
if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex) {
    return false;
} else {
    $domain = substr($email,$atIndex+1);
    $local = substr($email, $atIndex);
}
$localLen = strlen($local);
$domainLen = strlen($domain);
if($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64) {
    return false;
}else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255) {
    return false;
}
if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.') {
    return false;
} elseif (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local)) {
    return false;
}
if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain)) {
    return false;
} else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain)) {
    return false;
} else if (!(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain, "A"))) {
    return false;
}
return $isValid;
}

?>
```

I have set up check points for the code to display if it errors out and if it succeeds.

My problem is: it is telling me that it has succeeded in adding the row to the database but when I check my data base it is not showing the database as being populated in any way. I dont know where im going wrong since it is passing my check points.. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not checking for errors in your query:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO 68_users (email, pass, first_name, last_name, dob, gender,     phone, fanmail)
VALUES ('$email','$pass','$first_name','$last_name','$dob','$gender','$phone','$fanmail')");
```

Do this instead:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO 68_users (email, pass, first_name, last_name, dob, gender,     phone, fanmail)
VALUES ('$email','$pass','$first_name','$last_name','$dob','$gender','$phone','$fanmail')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, you should not even be using mysql_*. Use PDO or MySQLi instead. See [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers;)

Try changing

```
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

to:

```
if ( !mysqli_query($link, $query) )
{
    echo 'error: '.mysqli_error($link);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "mysql_*"?

Comment: You know how you're using `mysql_connect()`, `mysql_query()`, ect ect? Well, those functions have been deprecated. You should be using PDO or MySQLi. If you don't like OOP, use MySQLi.

Comment: `mysql_*` means "all the functions that start `mysql_`".

Comment: @TraeMoore Be sure to accept this answer if it was what you're looking for.

Comment: i did as you recommended i changed to mysqli and it is still not inputting into the table.. i dont know what to do. im going to edit my post to show what i changed it to.

Comment: ok i get injection, your basically editing one column at a time, corrrect?

Comment: i changed as recommended getting a blank error.. connected to db table -  error:  i'm completely lost at this point. i did forget to mention im teaching my self and its the first time ive worked with db

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22080/discussion-between-trae-moore-and-navnav)